# SDU setting in the connection string with oracle 11G

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, tnsnames, tns

I do not reference the sqlnet.ora file for the look-up and pretty much  provide the following TNS URL for the connectivity and I need to squeeze in a SDU setting in the below connection URL I was wondering where it would go and how the new url will look like?

Here is what I am using: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.191.231:1521:naladomain`

I now need to squezze in a custom sdu setting in the above TNS string.How do I do that ? :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the long TNS format (as per the `tnsnames.ora` file). Like this:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(SDU=32767)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.191.231)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=naladomain))
```

Change the values to meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks man took a year to look back at this message, we have solved this using the template example provided by oracle:jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description=(sdu=16384)(address=(host=${infra.jdbc.host})(protocol=tcp)(port=${infra.jdbc.port}))(connect_data=(sid=${infra.phr.jdbc.sid}))) the sesseion data unit 16384 was the magic number that always worked for us.